# Modifying python AST while preserving comments

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, transformer-model

I am currently working with the AST in python. I take in a python file, generate its AST, modify it, and then recompile back to source code. I'm using a transformer that adds a getter to a class (I am using a visitor pattern with ast.NodeTransformer). Currently my code works as expected but does not preserve comments, which is my issue. Below is my code:

```
#visits nodes and generates getters or setters
def genGet(file,type,func):
    global things
    things['func'] = func
    things['type'] = type
    with open(file) as f:
        code = f.read()             #get the code
    tree = ast.parse(code)          #make the AST from the code
    genTransformer().visit(tree)    #lets generate getters or setters depending on type argument given in our transformer so the genTransformer function
    source = meta.asttools.dump_python_source(tree) #recompile the modified ast to source code
    newfile = "{}{}".format(file[:-3],"_mod.py")
    print "attempting to write source code new file: {}".format(newfile) #tell everyone we will write our new source code to a file
    outputfile = open(newfile,'w+')
    outputfile.write(source)        #write our new source code to a file
    outputfile.close()


class genTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    ...
```

I have done some research on lib2to3 which apparently can preserve comments but have not found anything as of yet that helps with my problem. For example, I found the code below but don't really understand it. It appears to preserve comments but not allow my modifications. I get a missing attribute error when it runs.

```
import lib2to3
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from lib2to3 import pygram, pytree
import ast

def main():
    filename = "%s" % ("exfunctions.py")
    with open(filename) as f:
        code = f.read()
    drv = driver.Driver(pygram.python_grammar, pytree.convert)
    tree = drv.parse_string(code, True)
    # ast transfomer breaks if it is placed here
    print str(tree)
    return
```

I am having trouble finding a package or strategy to preserve comments whilst transforming an AST. Thus far my research has not helped me. What can I use that will allow me to modify an AST but also preserve the comments?

Comment: Comments are not part of the AST, just like they are not part of the generated bytecode for Python source. Like blank lines, they are discarded when creating the AST nodes.

Comment: The 2to3 library uses its own tokenizer and parser; the `lib2to3.pgen2.tokenize` source contains the comment: *It is designed to match the working of the Python tokenizer exactly, except that it produces COMMENT tokens for comments and gives type OP for all operators*

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  So does 2to3 lose comments in the conversion?

Comment: @IraBaxter: no, its custom parser preserves them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm confused: you said the AST does not have comments, but 2to3's custom parser preserves them.  Where?

Comment: The parse tree produced by the lib2to3 parser is not compatible with the AST module; I guess you'd have to see if you can turn the [fixers support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#fixers) into something you can reuse.

Comment: @IraBaxter: AST uses the normal Python parser. The `lib2to3` parser produces its own tree (not one compatible with the `ast` module). It preserves comments; the comment in `lib2to3.pytree` states: *This is a very concrete parse tree; we need to keep every token and even the comments and whitespace between tokens.*

Comment: Ah ok. So if I were to preserve comments, I'd need to reformat my code to work with the lib2to3 tree. That explains the error I was getting when attempting to run my transformer on the tree generated in my second code fragment.

Answer (score 3):

LibCST is a Python Concrete Syntax tree parser and toolkit which can be used to solve your problem.
It provides a syntax tree looks like ast but with formatting info preserved.
It also provides transformer pattern for tree modification.

https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST/

https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
import libcst as cst

class NameTransformer(cst.CSTTransformer):
    def leave_Name(self, original_node, updated_node):
        return cst.Name(updated_node.value.upper())
```

With a NameTransformer like this, we can transform all names in source code to upper case:

```
>>> m = cst.parse_module("def fn(): return (value)")
>>> m.visit(NameTransformer()).code

'def FN(): return VALUE'
```